# Saving Array content over two view controllers

Tags: uitableview, delegates, storyboard, uitabview

i have a slightly confusing problem here. I am using storyboard i have a tab view controller tab 1 has a table view controller (table 1) which on selection of a row goes to table 2 and some data is added to the table 2 here n it is shown on table 2 cell when i navigate back to table 1 and go forward again to table 2 that data is lost ..how can i save the data then so that it can still show the saved contents. thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question... Please, try to use proper English and punctuation.

Comment: see i have a navigation with a tab controller.. on the first tab i have a tableview(table1) which on selection goes to table 2 .here on table 2 i can add rows but wen i navigate back to table1 n den again go forward on table2 they are gone n my table is blank

Answer (score 0):

It's because the navigation controller releases the second view controller when you go back from table 2 to table 1. If there were no other references to the 2nd table view, it gets deallocated. I suppose you're also creating the table view every time you select a row in table 1. Try to keep a reference on the second table view, and not re-create it every time, only on initialization.

Comment: You may use one, but what delegate are you speaking of? When you create the navigation controller, presumably within your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method, keep a reference to your second table view. Even better, subclass the navigation controller, and make the second table view a @property of it, create it in the navigation controllers -init or -viewDidLoad method, and release it in -dealloc.

Comment: not solved still ..can sum one give an explanatory code (sorry I'm new to iOS programming)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need fixed data storage. You can use Apple's Core data for this. See Apples documentation on Core Data or see  "Pro Core Data for iOS" by Michael Privat. Then each view controller can store and retrieve data from the permanent store. Be aware that learning core data takes some effort, but it is worth because you will find yourself using it time and again. I also ran across this project [arraydatatable](http://dawtano.com/xc-project.zip) which provides a structured data solution without using core data. Also, since you mentioned that your are new to iOS you should read Apple's documentation on their recommended Model View Controller (MVC) structure. In that structure the Model is your data, the View is what you see on the screen, and the Controller controls the view as well as fetching and storing data to the model.